# .NET Framework dll Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json....'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am creating a c# .net framework library (.dll) that will act as a plugin for another piece of software. I want to use the Newtonsoft.json library but when the I call the json library I get the classic "FileNotFoundException":

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The .dll is definitely being copied to the directory I am trying to run the plugin from. A lot of others have had this issue and I have tried everything I've seen (updating, reinstalling, etc.) but no luck yet. Because this is a class library I do not have an "app.config" file to play with binding redirects, so I haven't been able to try that.

I have very basic code right now, this package is the only external reference I am using. I've only been working on this today, only ever trying with Newtonsoft.Json version 12.0.2. It is weird to me that it appears VS is looking for 12.0.0.0, however. This is not an option to download. Similarly, I've tried downgrading to version 11.0.2, and then it gives me the same error saying it can't find version 11.0.0.0.

Comment: I suggest that you can create another project to detect if it exits the problem.

Comment: Already done and no luck...another thing I tried was creating a brand new project and just referencing the .dll that I had downloaded (not using NuGet) and get the same results. I have also tried using a different package from NuGet (ServiceStack.Text) and get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Even though your project may not have an .app config, you can still view the package references by unloading your project and viewing the .csproj file.

To try and force a direct reference to Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.2, you can add this snippet

```
 <ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
    <Version>12.0.2</Version>
  </PackageReference>
 </ItemGroup>
```

I would recommend removing any other references in your .csproj for Newtonsoft.Json as well

Comment: Tried this, it does not change anything. I don't understand why the error says it is looking for version 12.0.0.0?

Comment: I've had this same issue multiple times and it seems to be resolved differently with each unique case. Hmm, let's see... if you Ctrl+Shift+F and search your entire solution for "12.0.0.0", do you see any matching lines for Newtonsoft?

Comment: The only matching lines were in some .cache files. i've tried just removing all of them and it still does this. I've also tried creating a brand new project and just referencing the .dll that I had downloaded (not using NuGet) and get the same results. Another thing I did was use a different package from NuGet (ServiceStack.Text) and get the same error.